# I am trying to make a google sheet that when I click a checkbox, it will clear the row and reset the the checkbox to unchecked

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make a google sheet that has 36 rows, the user will fill out information throughout a day and when the checkbox at the end is check the row will be cleared and the checkbox will go back to Unchecked or FALSE. I have code to clear the contents in a row and can assign it to a button but I would like to activate the code when checkbox is checked. Is that possible?

I  am new to this kind of coding and I may be way off. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

```
function clearRow2() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var workingCell =  activeSheet.getRange(10 , 13).getValue();

  if(workingCell = 1) {
    activeSheet.getRange("A10:L10").clearContent();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function clearRow2() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var workingcell=sh.getRange(10,13).getValue();
  if(workingCell == 1) {
    sh.getRange("A10:L10").clearContent();
  }
}
```